# Is it possible to check what is running inside a .war in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, war, talend

I've got a `Talend` process, deployed inside a `.war` file in a `Tomcat` app server. The `.war` has several jobs inside it, that are called using a get request pretty much like "http://server:port/TalendProject/method=runJob".

Not having the commercial license of `Talend` (using Open Studio at the moment) I don't have any way to control whether a job has failed or not in the middle of the execution.

I know I can check logs but not knowing the system I'm operating with, I can't be sure if a job has failed or is still running (after an exception for example).

My question is if there is any way to monitor the job that is running inside the `Tomcat`, this is, if there is any way to show the process that is being running.

My guess, but I'm not sure is that there is no way since the `Talend` Job is running encapsulated by the `Talend` `.war`, so the only thing I will see is the java calling this `.war` and everything below will be hidden.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about **Talend**, but I think you can use **JConsole** or better **VisualVm** to monitor your Tomcat server via JMX Agent. In order to monitor any Java application (as Tomcat) you have to invoke it with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` if tomcat is running in localhost.

If Tomcat is running in another host, you need to configure at least  port JMX property `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=XXXX`.

In order to add these properties to run tomcat, you have to change `CATALINA_OPTS` variable located into `$TOMACT_HOME\bin\catalina.sh` or `$TOMACT_HOME\bin\catalina.bat` file.

You have full documentation about Java JMX Agent monitoring [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html)

This way you can monitor threads, memory consumption, gc activity, do profiling, thread dump, ... maybe it helps you to understand .